# Why do I need to wrap setState callback in an anonymous arrow function for it to run after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm going out of my mind with this one. I have a react class that has some methods like this:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    }, this.doSearch());
}

changePage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        searchPage: e,
        isLoading: true
    }, this.doSearch());
}
```

I use `handleSubmit` when the user clicks submit on the search form in this component's render.

```
<button type="button" id="btn-search" onClick={event => this.handleSubmit(event)}>Search</button>
```

This works out fine, it submits, sets the state and then calls this.doSearch after it sets `isLoading: true`.

Once I get the search results, I call a child component to display the result list, and I give it a handler for when the user clicks on pagination:

```
<ResultList searchResult={searchResult} changePage={this.changePage} />
```

From within the child, there is just a simple span with an onClick:

```
<span onClick={event => props.changePage(props.searchResult.page + 1)}>&gt;&gt;</span>
```

So when the user clicks on the next page ... pager, the handler is called. I can log out `e` and see the number has incremented. I then call setState and tell it to use the parent class's `doSearch()` after the state has been updated. Rather, that is my goal. But it keeps running `doSearch()` before the state has updated. But I know at some point the state finishes updating because by the time the component re-renders, the state has the updated `searchPage`.

The only way I seem to be able to get it to run my callback AFTER the state is done updating is to wrap it in an arrow function, so that it looks like so:

```
changePage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        searchPage: e,
        isLoading: true
    }, () => {
        this.doSearch()
    });
}
```

This is only an issue with `changePage` which is passed to the child component and then called from there with the intention of incrementing or decrementing `searchPage`. Calling `this.doSearch()` from the submit handler is fine.

I get the feeling I'm not understanding scoping or this.state or instances or something....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is confusing you is the order of evaluation in JavaScript, it's nothing React-specific.

If you have

```
foo(this.doSearch())
```

`doSearch` will be called *immediately*. That is, even *before* `foo` is called, and then the *result* of `doSearch` will be passed to `foo`.

You don't want that, you want to pass the *computation* to the `setState` function. That is, you want to pass the *function* `doSearch`, not the result of the function.

So what you actually want is

```
changePage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        searchPage: e,
        isLoading: true
    }, this.doSearch);
}
```

Which means you're passing the *function* `this.doSearch` to `setState`. Of course, `this.doSearch` is equivalent to `() => this.doSearch()` (both are functions that, when called, call `this.doSearch()`).

Comment: Ah... I shouldn't have `()`ed it. But for some reason `handleSubmit` seems to work, but maybe it's  just fast enough that the loading message doesn't really seem impacted. That was hours of my life I won't get back. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One calls it immediately and passes its return value as the callback to be used (bad). The other creates a function and **that** is used as the callback (good).

Its like accidentally writing an event listener like this:

```
// Assign console.log as the callbak
// Will print the event argument on click
// (just mentioning for completeness)
addEventlistener("click", console.log)

// vs

// Immediately print "a"
// Add undefined as callback
// (your first example [bad])
addEventlistener("click", console.log("a")):

// vs

// Add function that will print "a" after a click
// (your second example [good])
addEventlistener("click", () => console.log("a"))
```