# Map is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I am trying to delete the element I have clicked on

My app.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {

        ninja: [
            {
                name: 'Ryu',
                age: 30,
                belt: 'black',
                id: 1
            }, {
                name: 'Jacy',
                age: 34,
                belt: 'yellow',
                id: 2
            }, {
                name: 'Ikenna',
                age: 20,
                belt: 'green',
                id: 3
            }, {
                name: 'Cole',
                age: 50,
                belt: 'red',
                id: 4
            }
        ]

    }

}
    deleteNinja (itemToBeDeleted) {
        console.log(itemToBeDeleted)
    }
    render = () => <div>
        {this
            .state
            .ninja
            .map(function (ninja) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div>{ninja.name}</div>
                        <div>{ninja.age}</div>
                        <div>{ninja.belt}</div>
                        <button
                            onClick={this
                            .state
                            .deleteNinja
                            .bind(this)}>Delete</button>
                    </div>
  )

              
            })}

    </div>
}
```

When I add the function deleteninja to my button it tells me cannot read state of undefined. I read something about binding it and still it wont do it. If I remove the button everything works fine

Comment: You don't need `state.deleteNinja`. `deleteNinja` is part of the component, not the state.  Try just `this.deleteNinja()`.

Comment: it says that deleteNinja is undefined :S

Comment: I don't see how `deleteNinja()` can be undefined, it is literally there just the next line before `render()` in the code posted.  Are you sure you have `<button onClick={(ninja) => this.deleteNinja(ninja)} />`?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2b81b2bf14c3e6d3a2a33d22cff76737

Comment: Oh, I see!  Sorry, updated answer...   `.map(function (ninja) { ....}, this);`, pass `this`!  It's not that deleteNinja is undefined, the error there says that you cannot call deleteNinja ON undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give `map` a `function() {}` if you want auto binding, use an arrow function.

Also, `onClick` wants you to give it a function that it should call later.  You are passing it `undefined` because it will be called as you `map`.  See my answer dealing with the same issue here: [Why do I need to wrap setState callback in an anonymous arrow function for it to run after state change?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63839954/691711).

```
onClick={console.log("Hello")} // console.log NOW, call undefined later

// vs

onClick={() => console.log("Hello")} // do nothing NOW, call console.log later
```

Try the following:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {

          ninja: [
              {
                  name: 'Ryu',
                  age: 30,
                  belt: 'black',
                  id: 1
              }, {
                  name: 'Jacy',
                  age: 34,
                  belt: 'yellow',
                  id: 2
              }, {
                  name: 'Ikenna',
                  age: 20,
                  belt: 'green',
                  id: 3
              }, {
                  name: 'Cole',
                  age: 50,
                  belt: 'red',
                  id: 4
              }
          ]

      }

    }
    deleteNinja (itemToBeDeleted) {
        console.log("Will delete");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(itemToBeDeleted, null, 4));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.ninja.map(ninja => (
                    <div key={ninja.id}>
                        <div>{ninja.name}</div>
                        <div>{ninja.age}</div>
                        <div>{ninja.belt}</div>
                        <button onClick={() => this.deleteNinja(ninja)}>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks  I dont really get it I think I have to read some more on this. Before I tried doing what HoldOffHunger said but it just told me undefined when i clicked and not telling me which element was clicked. But this works ill try to understand it better thanks

Comment: just to clarify is it a callbackfunction or am i completly lost?

Comment: `onClick` is what will be called whenever an element is clicked.  That's why it wants a function reference or a function object or some function.  You weren't giving it that, you were giving it `undefined` because you called the function that you were "trying" to pass as you mapped.  So yes, it is a callback function in that sense.

Comment: Why wont this update the render I checked the data on click it removes the element clicked and keeps the others? https://gyazo.com/394adb15f7fbc7d57e39af7fef58be25

Comment: @Jerry See: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/1218980)

Comment: Because you don't map `data`, you map `ninja`.  You're ending up with `{ninja, data}` instead of just `{ninja}`.  Rename `data` to `ninja` for the fastest fix or `setState({ninja: data})`.

Comment: figured it out have to refer to ninja: data and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do three things: 1) Set your onClick() to the right location for the function, 2) Pass the ninja argument to the function, not the `this` argument, 3) Pass *`this`* to your `map()` function...

```
<button onClick={(ninja) => this.deleteNinja(ninja)} />
```

And map should be like this...

```
.map(function (ninja) {
}, this);
```

1. Notice that before you had `this.state.deleteNinja.bind()`, and I replaced this with `(ninja) => this.deleteNinja(ninja)`.
2. Notice before you passed `this` to be deleted, `deleteNinja.bind(this)`.  Well, you probably don't want to delete the `this` app, and you have a `ninja` var that you're mapping on, and a `deleteNinja()` function, so, probably ideal to pass the ninja, like so, `this.deleteNinja(ninja)`.

Comment: If you're going to use an arrow function for the `map` callback, then the `this` param isn't necessary.